# Intermittent error with Scanner.read() not picking up delimiter

Tags: java, android, java.util.scanner

I'm maintaining some legacy Android code which reads "calibration" values for our product from a text file. In theory, the user can manually adjust the calibration file, so every 10 seconds we reload the file to check for new values. The user can also screw the file up, so if the file is found to be unreadable/unparseable we write out a default version of the "calibration".

Here's the relevant bit of code where we read and parse terms:

```
public boolean ReadCalibFromFile() {
    boolean res = true;
    String title = null;
    String data = null;
    try {
        File direct = new File(WSDataStorageUtils.getInstance().getCurrentDirLocation());
        if (!direct.exists()) {
            File filesDirectory = new File(WSDataStorageUtils.getInstance().getCurrentDirLocation());
            filesDirectory.mkdirs();
        }
    File calib=new File(new File(WSDataStorageUtils.getInstance().getCurrentDirLocation()), currentCalibFile + ".txt");
    Logger.i(tag, "Using calibration file: " + currentCalibFile + ".txt");
    if(!calib.exists()){
        Logger.i(tag, "Calibration file doesn't exist! Recreating...");
        SaveCalibFiles();

        // having saved the standard files, if we can't find the file we might have a wrong name
        if (!calib.exists()) {
            Logger.e(tag, "This file: " + currentCalibFile + ", doesn't exist, returning to default");
            currentCalibFile = DEFAULT_CALIB_FILE;
            calib=new File(new File(WSDataStorageUtils.getInstance().getCurrentDirLocation()), currentCalibFile + ".txt");
        }

        if (!calib.exists()) { // even after returning to default value
            // we are really screwed
            Logger.e(tag, "Can't even recover to default file! This is bad!");
            return false;
        }
    }
    Scanner read = new Scanner(calib);
    read.useDelimiter("=|\\n");
    while (read.hasNext()) {
        title = read.next();
        data = read.next();
        if (!nextData(data, title)) {
            Logger.e(tag, "Error in reading from Calibration file");
            Logger.e(tag, "title = " + title + " data = " + data);
            res = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    read.close();
    if(VersionChecked == false) {
        res = false;
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Logger.e("ReadCalibFromfile", "Received an exception: " + e.getMessage());
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
    e.printStackTrace(pw);
    String stackTrace = sw.toString();
    Logger.e("ReadCalibFromFile", stackTrace);
    Logger.e(tag, "Last good values from file were:");
    Logger.e(tag, "title = " + title + " data = " + data);
    res = false;
}
return res;
}
```

Most of the time this is working fine. We left the app running over the weekend (no-one was editing the calibration file) and in the middle of the night the file somehow had an error. The code "fixed" the error by overwriting the old file  - but it's the error which I don't understand.

Logs excerpted:

```
2018-07-13 00:25:12.441 [Thread-240] INFO  Calibration: Using calibration file: name.txt
2018-07-13 00:25:12.470 [Thread-240] ERROR ReadCalibFromfile: Received an exception: null
2018-07-13 00:25:12.470 [Thread-240] ERROR ReadCalibFromFile: java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:968)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:941)
    at com.mycompany.myapp.Calibration.ReadCalibFromFile(Calibration.java:190)
    at com.mycompany.myapp.Calibration.run(Calibration.java:108)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

2018-07-13 00:25:12.471 [Thread-240] ERROR Calibration: Last good values from file were:
2018-07-13 00:25:12.471 [Thread-240] ERROR Calibration: title = Version=1.1
firstRegionLimit=8
secondRegionLimit=50
CoafPressRegion0_0=-3.0
CoafPressRegion0_1=3.0
CoafPressRegion0_2=0.01
CoafPressRegion0_3=0.0
CoafPressRegion1_0=1.5
CoafPressRegion1_1=1.4
CoafPressRegion1_2=0.02
CoafPressRegion1_3=0.0
CoafPressRegion2_0=-10.0
CoafPressRegion2_1=5.0
CoafPressRegion2_2=0.015
CoafPressRegion2_3=0.0


*= "   Version : VERSION NUMBER - PLEASE DON'T CHANGE"
*= "   firstRegionLimit :  the high limit of the first range "
*= "   secondRegionLimit : the high limit of the second range "
*= "   mCoafPressRegion :  the coefficient for a certain region "
 data = null
```

As you can see - the app fails to find any delimiters, although the delimiters have been set to "=" and "\n". To be clear, this code works on exactly this file 99% of the time. The entire first "read", which is supposed to be up to a delimiter, holds a text which contains many delimiters (even if you don't believe me that there are real '\n' in between each line, you can see the '=').

When this function returns false I rewrite the file and all works fine afterwards....for a few more hours, it is read correctly every 10 seconds and then a little over 8 hours later it has the same problem.

Has anyone else encountered such an issue? I can't figure out how it would be a timing isue, since the file is read once every 10 seconds, and correctly closed the time before.

Comment: The problem is probably the `while` loop, the loop's condition is `read.hasNext()` but inside of it you call `read.next()` twice.

Comment: Hi @Titus, how does that explain the entire file (with many tokens in it) being swallowed on the first read()? Also how does it explain the fact that it works over 2000 times correctly, then doesn't work once then works a few thousand times more correctly?